# Extract real time data from ajax website in python

Tags: python, ajax

I would like to extract real time data from a webpage:
http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/forex-rates/

I am programming in Python and I did an urlopen to take the htmlcode. Then I used regular expressions to extract the numbers.
Problem is that I have to do an urlopen each second to get the latest data, its long not reliable and not clean... Can someone help **without having to refresh the webpage**?
thanks!

Comment: Re-write this question.  It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish, what you have already tried, or why it didn't work.

Comment: I want to fill a dictionnary with the forex data, for instance: EUR/USD 1,4401 13:14:12 My code atm looks like:
import re
import urllib

f = urllib.urlopen(http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/forex-rates)
g = f.read()

then i use regexes to search the data inside the full page html code.
I have to do that urlopen every second to get the latests results...
I dont want to have to refresh with urlopen each second.

Comment: Put your explanation *in the question*.  For that matter, put a full explanation in *every* question you ask.

Comment: Take a look at how it gets its data by using something like Firebug. It's a comet server which keeps feeding data on the same resource. You can keep fetching and parse that data if you want to. Be cautious though; it's not likely to be legal to get the data and use it in something else without permission (not that I've checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you going.  Try the following from the command line:

```
curl -d '[{"channel":"/meta/connect","connectionType":"xhr-streaming","id":"15","clientId":"14799ac3-a0ac-43ab-8bb6-baad56886e11"}]' "http://ttpush.fxstreet.com/http_push/connect"
```

As you can see, as long as you keep the connection open, the site keeps pushing more data to you.   I would think that would be easy to convert to Python.